# How to uninstall a Prestashop module programmatically?

Tags: module, prestashop, uninstallation, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

First of all, excuse my bad english

My original idea was to add some options to the module's uninstall menu, but since I couldn't find any hook that allows me to do this, I decided to create an uninstall button that shows my own menu. I would like to know if this is possible.

An example of the options I would like to add is if certain tables are removed from the database on uninstall.

Comment: You should call uninstall function of a module in your code.